# Why do I get a ModuleNotFoundError for winreg on a Linux system?

Tags: python, python-3.6, winreg

'winreg' module is not found python 3.6.7. I am not facing this problem in Python 3.4.

Is any third-party app in 'winreg' that I can use same code or how can I solve this.

```
jaki@jaki-notebook:~$ python3 -V
Python 3.6.7
jaki@jaki-notebook:~$ python3
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from winreg import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'winreg'
>>>
```

> **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'winreg'**

Comment: Are you on windows? Are you sure you're using Python 3? It's named `_winreg` in Python 2. Can you give a full account of how you are calling it? See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: I am using Linux and python version is "Python 3.6.7"

Comment: If you're on Linux, there is no Windows registry. So there is no `winreg` module because it couldn't do anything even if it were there. If the `winreg` import is coming from a third-party package, it probably should have an alternate mechanism for configuration on non-Windows systems. If it's your own code, you will just need to use a different configuration mechanism rather than `winreg` when on a non-Windows system.

Comment: @Jaki: When you say "I am not facing this problem in Python 3.4": is the Python 3.4 distribution in question also installed on a Linux system, or is that a Windows system by any chance?

Comment: Why are you trying to import `winreg` on Linux?

Comment: For deploying a project in heroku. I am just quick test this project in windows and that's time I am not facing the problem and I did not know than "winreg" is windows base package. Is there any python module like winreg?

Comment: @Jaki The `winreg` python module uses the Windows registry. There is no equivalent on Linux. See https://superuser.com/questions/295635/linux-equivalent-of-windows-registry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not work on linux because this package `expose functions  of the Windows registry API to Python`

Read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html) documentation on python offical website